# Material-UI: How to show search icon in input field in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am using [material ui](https://material-ui.com). I want to show `search icon` in input field as shown in image
[image]

I am using [this API](https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/)

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/4ryxnokj4x) is my code

I am able to show `TextField` but I am not able to add a search icon. 
Could you please add how to add ?

```
 <TextField id="standard-bare" defaultValue="Bare" margin="normal" />
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to use [Input Adornments](https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/#input-adornments).

For example:

```
// imports
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";

// render

<TextField
  label="With normal TextField"
  InputProps={{
    endAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment>
        <IconButton>
          <SearchIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </InputAdornment>
    )
  }}
/>
```

Here is a demo:

```js
const {
  TextField,
  InputAdornment,
  IconButton,
  SearchIcon,
  Icon
} = window['material-ui'];

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TextField
        label="With normal TextField"
        InputProps={{
          endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment>
              <IconButton>
                <Icon>search</Icon>
              </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
          )
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: What's the need for the `IconButton` here ?  To make the search icon clickable or something?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan yes. The icon is basically an SVG element, so you need to put in on a button.

Answer (score 14):

You simply need to import inputAdornment

`import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment';`

and add InputProps to textField like this

```
InputProps={{
  endAdornment: (
    <InputAdornment position="start">
      <SearchIcon />
    </InputAdornment>
   )
  }}
```

plz find the attached img for demo of your required solution.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I used only `IconButton`

```
import {  TextField, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';

import { SearchOutlined } from '@material-ui/icons';
```

my example:

```
             <TextField
                fullWidth
                id="standard-bare"
                variant="outlined"
                defaultValue="How can we help"
                InputProps={{
                  endAdornment: (
                    <IconButton>
                      <SearchOutlined />
                    </IconButton>
                  ),
                }}
              />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [InputBase](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/input-base/)

```
<Box sx={{display:"flex",justifyContent:"space-between", border:1, borderRadius:4}}>

    <InputBase />

    <IconButton>
      <BiSearch />
    </IconButton>

 </Box>
```