# How can I get rid of input field in KeyboardDatePicker from Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Trying to use KeyboardDatePicker. In one form it is perfectly ok with input field, but in other place I need just an icon to open and choose the date.

```
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          disableToolbar
          variant="inline"
          // inputVariant="outlined"
          autoOk
          format="dd/MM/yyyy"
          id="date-picker-inline"
          // label="Date picker inline"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
          InputAdornmentProps={{ position: "start"}}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'change date',
          }}
        />
```

Is it possible to set this with props?

Comment: may be this help .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54970335/material-ui-how-to-show-search-icon-in-input-field-in-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of css you can hide it

```
<KeyboardDatePicker
  disableToolbar
  variant="inline"
  format="DD/MM/YYYY"
  value={selectedDate}
  onChange={onChange}
  className="styledKeyboardDatePicker"
  autoOk
  InputAdornmentProps={{ position: "start"}}
  KeyboardButtonProps={{
    'aria-label': 'change date',
  }}
/>
```

```css
.styledKeyboardDatePicker .MuiInputBase-input {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
}
```

Another workaround is disabling it. It doesn't allow you to change input but icon still works.

```
<KeyboardDatePicker
  disableToolbar
  variant="inline"
  format="DD/MM/YYYY"
  value={selectedDate}
  onChange={onChange}
  autoOk
  InputAdornmentProps={{ position: "start"}}
  KeyboardButtonProps={{
    'aria-label': 'change date',
  }}
  disable
/>
```